# How to replace symbol || with |""| using sed

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I have a file that uses `|` as a delimiter. Some of the records have empty cell as `||` (nothing inside). I am trying to replace them with `|""|` with following sed command:

```
sed -i 's/\|\|/\|""|/g' file
```

But the result wasn't what I expected.

Input file

```
A|B|C|D|||E
```

Desired output:

```
A|B|C|D|""|""|E
```

**Note that the beginning and ending of records doesn't have "|"**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: BTW: In sed, alternation is `\|` not `|`, so you don't actually want to escape those `|`s.

Comment: This is a strange thing to do for a CSV file: usually either all the fields are quoted, or only the ones that contain the separator are quoted. Your question makes me thing the process that consumes your data is broken.

Comment: Your question asks "How?", but I suspect that you're wondering "Why?" It may help you to understand if you try `echo cat | sed 's/a/aa/g'` or `echo caaat | sed 's/a/aa/g'`. You'll end up with `caat` or `caaaaaat`, respectively, and not an infinite loop -- because, when `sed` makes a substitution with an `s` command, it *doesn't look in the new (replacement) text for further matches*. E.g., when it changes `cat` to `caat`, it *doesn't* say, "Oh! There are two more `a`s that I need to match and replace." cont...

Comment: cont... The point is, when it changes `D||` to `D|""|`, it doesn't consider the `|` after the quotes as a candidate for further replacement, so the `||E` doesn't change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just repeat the substitution until output doesn't change:

```
$ echo 'A|B|C|D|||E' | sed ':X;s/||/|""|/g;tX'
A|B|C|D|""|""|E
```

where

- `:X` sets the label `X`
- `t X` go to label `X` if `s///` was successful